# Geometric Theories have models in any Grothendieck Topos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, topos-theory, categorical-logic

This question is linked to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253960/models-of-a-theory-in-an-elementary-topos) one.

My question is:

> Is it true any consistent geometric (here I mean coherent theory, different books have different standards) theory $T$ has a model in a Grothendieck Topos?

---

I can sketch why I do believe it might be true.

Since $T$ is consistent (and finitary first order) there is a geometric morphism $$M: B(T) \to \text{Set},$$ where $B(T)$ is the classifying topos of $T$.

For a Grothendieck topos $G$ a model would be a geometric morphism $N: B(T) \to G$.

But since $G$ is a Grothendiek topos it is a reflexive subcategory of $\text{Set}^C$ and the functor $\text{Set}^C \to G$ is left exact so that one can build a model of $T$ on $G$ by building a model of $T$ on $\text{Set}^C $

All in all it's enough to build a geometric functor $B(T) \to \text{Set}^C$.

Here, a trick: $$\text{Geom}(B(T), \text{Set}^C) \subset \text{Fun}(B(T) \times  C, \text{Set}).$$ Now, I do have a functor $B(T) \to Set$, so I hope there is a suitable functor $C \to \text{Set}$ which concludes the story.

Comment: See my answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98729/topos-without-point-from-the-point-of-view-of-logic/98751#98751

Comment: I was meaning coherent theory, which is what is meant by geometric in Sheaves in Geometry and Logic. Anyway very interesting comment!

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "consistent"?

Comment: $T \not \vdash \bot.$

Comment: If this implies having a model in $\mathrm{Set}$, then this is trivially true: fix a geometric morphism $B(T)\leftarrow\mathrm{Set}$ (geometric morphisms are usually thought to point in the opposite direction from what you use) and then, for any other Grothendieck topos $G$, take the composite $B(T)\leftarrow\mathrm{Set}\leftarrow G$, where $\mathrm{Set}\leftarrow G$ is the unique geometric morphism (for whose existence suffices that $G$ is Grothendieck)

Comment: What is the morphism $G \to Set$? Can you give me reference?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning, but in any case any geometric theory has a universal model in its classifying topos, by its very definition. You only problem could be that the classifying topos is empty, but you already ruled it out with a condition of consistency. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ivan First let us make it straight. A geometric morphism $f:E\to F$ consists of an adjoint pair $f_*:E\to F$, $f^*:F\to E$, with $f^*$ left and $f_*$ right, and $f^*$ in addition exact. For a Grothendieck topos $G$ there is a unique geometric morphism to $\mathrm{Set}$, with $f_*(X)=\hom(1,X)$ for $X\in G$ and $f^*(S)=\coprod_S1$ for $S\in\mathrm{Set}$.

Comment: Perfect, this is an answer.

Comment: Note however that as mentioned in the link provided by @FrançoisG.Dorais, there exist geometric theories consistent in your sense but having models not in every Grothendieck topos (which implies in particular that they do not have any model in $\mathrm{Set}$).

Comment: @AntonFetisov OP asks whether the theory has a model in *every* Grothendieck topos (this is not clear from the statement but becomes apparent from the subsequent reasoning in the question).

Comment: Why is that functor unique? If the topos is just elementary, when that functor exists?

Comment: @Ivan It exists iff the topos has arbitrary set-indexed copowers of the terminal (i. e. $f^*(S)$ exists for every set $S$). It is unique if it exists, since $f^*$ must preserve the terminal and arbitrary colimits, and in $\mathrm{Set}$, any object $S$ is $\coprod_S1$, so $f^*(S)=f^*(\coprod_S1)\cong\coprod_Sf^*(1)$ must hold.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე The OP means coherent theory (the terminology "geometric" is unfortunate), so the model in $\mathcal{S}et$ always exists (for consistent theories).

Comment: @godelian Yes, true. The link by François above concerns an example of a consistent (in the sense of having nontrivial classifying topos) infinitary geometric theory without $\mathrm{Set}$-models. Do you mean that also there "geometric" would be inappropriate?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე There it is ok; the standard usage from the Elephant volumes is "coherent" for the finitary case and "geometric" in case of infinitary disjunctions. The older book by Maclane & Moerdijk uses "geometric" for what Johnstone calls "coherent".